# Populating TabLayout using FragmentStatePagerAdapter with only selected items

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, fragmentstatepageradapter

I am using `Android TabLayout` to generate `tabs` with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` as `adapter`. Now with this code it generates the `items` on every `tab` when I scroll it.

`SongManager.getAudioListFromResponse(result)` gives a `List` of `Audio` objects which each have a `String` called genre. For example the first audio has rock genre and the second one has blues genre.

The `getItem()` in `SongListAdapter` makes a new Fragment that uses attributes of one `Audio` and adds it to the `recylerview` to be displayed. (I can add the `SongListFragment` if needed).

At the moment this code is filling all the tabs with the same `Fragments`. It does not matter which `tab` I select, they are all the same.

My question would be.. How can I make it so it would get the `Audio's genre` and sort it accordingly.

Or how can I catch in the `main activity` Songmanager.getSonglist... that the tab has been swapped and what the title of the tab is.

And also how can I make it so that when I choose I can add a song to `recommended` tab.

Here is the code where I create the `TabLayout` :

```
SongManager.getSonglist(getApplicationContext(), new OkHttp3Connection.OkHttp3RequestCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String result, String user_tag) {

            ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

            SongListAdapter songListAdapter =
                    new SongListAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getApplicationContext());
            songListAdapter.setAudioList(SongManager.getAudioListFromResponse(result));
            viewPager.setAdapter(songListAdapter);

            // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
            TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

            songListAdapter.setItemListener(new SongListAdapter.SongListViewPagerListViewItemListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(Audio audio) {
                    goToCameraView();
                    songGraph.setAudio(audio);
                }
            });

            // Iterate over all tabs and set the custom view
            for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {

                TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);

                if (tab != null) {
                    tab.setCustomView(songListAdapter.getTabView(i));
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String error, String user_tag) {
            System.out.println("HTTP Error: " + error);
        }
    });
```

And the whole `SongListAdapter` class:

```
public class SongListAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    String tabTitles[] = new String[]{"Recommended", "Popular", "Rock", "Pop", "Blues", "Chill"};
    Context context;



    private ArrayList<Audio> audioList;

    public SongListAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabTitles.length;
    }

    @Override
    public SongListFragment getItem(int position) {
        SongListFragment slf = new SongListFragment();
        slf.setAudioList(getAudioList());
        slf.setItemOnClickListener(new SongListFragment.SongListItemOnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(Audio audio) {
                System.out.println("asdfdas");
                itemListener.onClick(audio);
            }
        });
        return slf;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        return tabTitles[position];
    }

    public View getTabView(int position) {
        View tab = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        TextView tv = tab.findViewById(R.id.custom_text);
        tv.setText(tabTitles[position]);
        return tab;
    }

    public ArrayList<Audio> getAudioList() {
        return audioList;
    }

    public void setAudioList(ArrayList<Audio> audioList) {
        this.audioList = audioList;
    }

    SongListViewPagerListViewItemListener itemListener;

    public void setItemListener(SongListViewPagerListViewItemListener itemListener) {
        this.itemListener = itemListener;
    }

    public interface SongListViewPagerListViewItemListener {
        void onClick(Audio audio);
    }
}
```

Whole result looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer for what understand from your question, that is you want to show different list of Audio based on genre in different tabs.

Okay, so I think the first problem is with how you return fragment's instance from SongsListAdapter's **getItem** method i.e.

```
@Override
    public SongListFragment getItem(int position) {
        SongListFragment slf = new SongListFragment();
        slf.setAudioList(getAudioList());
        slf.setItemOnClickListener(new SongListFragment.SongListItemOnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(Audio audio) {
                System.out.println("asdfdas");
                itemListener.onClick(audio);
            }
        });
        return slf;
    }
```

Here you are supposed to return different Instances of SongListFragment having filtered AudioList based on Genre.
So this could look somethink like:

```
@Override
    public SongListFragment getItem(int position) {
        SongListFragment slf = new SongListFragment();
        slf.setAudioList(filterBasedOnGenre(getAudioList(), tabTitles[position]));
        slf.setItemOnClickListener(new SongListFragment.SongListItemOnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(Audio audio) {
                System.out.println("asdfdas");
                itemListener.onClick(audio);
            }
        });
        return slf;
    }

public ArrayList<Audio> filterBasedOnGenre(ArrayList<Audio> audioList, String genreToFilter)
    {
        ArrayList<Audio> filteredAudioList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Audio audio : audioList) {
            if (audio.getGenre().equalsIgnoreCase(genreToFilter)) {
                filteredAudioList.add(audio);
            }  
        }
        return filteredAudioList; 
    }
```

Considering Audio looks like this:

```
    public class Audio {
           public Audio(String songName, String singer, String genre) {
                this.songName = songName;
                this.singer = singer;
                this.genre = genre;
            }

            private String songName;
            private String singer;
            private String genre;

            public String getSongName() {
                return songName;
            }

            public void setSongName(String songName) {
                this.songName = songName;
            }

            public String getSinger() {
                return singer;
            }

            public void setSinger(String singer) {
                this.singer = singer;
            }

            public String getGenre() {
                return genre;
            }

            public void setGenre(String genre) {
                this.genre = genre;
            }
        }
```

Hope it helps.
Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: I am sorry, I actually figured out something close to this out but forgot to answer it here. Anyways, thank you for answering and I im guessing I'll give you the bounty but I will wait a day or so. Maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: Actually, I know there are better ways to implement, because I myself have tried these.I wanted to give simplest fix in less time. I'm glad you found solution by yourself, well done.

Answer (score 1):

SO Your Figure out solution yourself good.
I am currently working on media player app so if you want to cache your songadapater or whatever you need to create cache file to store your array object.

this method to **writes cache** file.

```
void createdcachedreadfile(Context con, String filename) throws IOException {
    String tempfile = null;
    for (Songpojo file : songpojoList) {
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = con.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(songpojoList);
            oos.close();
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

And to retrive

```
  public Object readCaheFile(Context context1, String filename) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    FileInputStream fis = context1.openFileInput(filename);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    Object object = ois.readObject();
    return object;
}
```

Maybe this still Helpful

Happy coding!!!!